# How to "sort" and "limit" results in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, go

I'm trying to execute a query with "sort" and "limit". With [mgo](https://github.com/go-mgo/mgo) you could do  `Find(nil).Sort(“-when”).Limit(10)` but the [new, official mongo driver](https://godoc.org/github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/mongo) has no such methods. How can I sort and "limit" with the new driver?

Comment: Presumably you'd use [`findopt.Sort`](https://godoc.org/github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/mongo/findopt#FindBundle.Sort) to build options for `Find`. Unfortunately, it takes an `interface{}` argument, the documentation says nothing useful, and there are no examples in the documentation or GitHub.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The official driver is not straightforward as `mgo`. You can do sort and limit using the `findopt.Limit` and `findopt.Sort`.

You can see examples from the official repository.

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/blob/5fea1444e52844a15513c0d9490327b2bd89ed7c/mongo/crud_spec_test.go#L364

Comment: Not being straightforward is an understatement. It's total rubbish

Comment: This one is deprecated. Use `options.Find()` instead.

Answer (score 27):

In the current version [mongo-go-driver v1.0.3](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/releases/tag/v1.0.3), the options are simplified. For example to perform find, sort and limit:

```
import (
"go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
"go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
"go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
)

options := options.Find()

// Sort by `_id` field descending
options.SetSort(bson.D{{"_id", -1}})

// Limit by 10 documents only 
options.SetLimit(10)

cursor, err := collection.Find(context.Background(), bson.D{}, options)
```

See more available options on [godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options). Especially [FindOptions](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options#FindOptions) for all possible options for `Find()`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
findOptions := options.Find()
findOptions.SetLimit(2)
findOptions.SetSkip(2)
...
cursor, err := collection.Find(context.Background(), bson.M{}, findOptions)
```

resource at https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/mongodb-go-driver-tutorial

Answer (score 5):

you need import "github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/options" package to build a `findOptions`.

```golang
import github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/options

findOptions := options.Find() // build a `findOptions`
findOptions.SetSort(map[string]int{"when": -1}) // reverse order by `when`
findOptions.SetSkip(0) // skip whatever you want, like `offset` clause in mysql
findOptions.SetLimit(10) // like `limit` clause in mysql

// apply findOptions
cur, err := collection.Find(context.TODO(), bson.D{}, findOptions)
// resolve err

for cur.Next(context.TODO()) {
   // call cur.Decode()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The sort-option apparently requires you to add a `map[string]interface{}` where you can specify a field as key and a sortOrder as value (where 1 means ascending and -1 means descending) as following:

```
sortMap := make(map[string]interface{})
sortMap["version"] = 1
opt := findopt.Sort(sortMap)
```

As far as I can see this means that you are only able to properly sort results by one sortField because keys in a go map are stored in a random order.

Answer (score 3):

ONE LINE OPTION

I know there is already a lot of answers but **you can do it as one line** (if you need it for any case of yours)

```
// From the Doc
// func (f *FindOptions) SetSort(sort interface{}) *FindOptions

cursor, err := collection.Find(context.Background(), bson.M{}, options.Find().SetSort(map[string]int{"when": -1}).SetLimit(10))
```

*SetSort() and the others* currently returns the parent pointer itself