# Pagination with JQuery on HTML Page

Tags: html, jquery, mongodb

I'm using Go to write the backend with MongoDB. I am using JQuery AJAX to send requests to the API.

I have an API that accepts parameters (page, limit, offset) and returns all records as a response. I want to perform pagination and send these parameters on `page Number button click`. I have approx 4,50,000 records in the collection.

I have searched some examples using pagination plugin but from what I understood it will first load all records from DB then perform pagination but I do not want to load all records because I am already sending (page, limit, offset parameters to limit records. How we can do that using HTML and JQuery?

```
<a href='#' onclick='getRecords(page,limit,offset)'>1</a>
```

I am using using Find().skip().limit().All(&result) in golang. And My HTML code is like first table show first 10 rows from db and then

```
<a herf='' onclick='getRecords(1,10,0)'>1</a> 
<a herf='' onclick='getRecords(2,10,10)'>2</a> 
<a herf='' onclick='getRecords(3,10,20)'>3</a>
```

...

```
function getRecords(page,limit,offset)
{
$.ajax(){}
}
```

I want to do it dynamic with next and prev like pagination

Comment: My understanding is that you are able to hit the API and get the results you want and you are looking for a solution using JQuery to display the results on page click. Is this so? If yes see my example.

Comment: @Steven Eckhoff I have re-post the question. I am getting my results on page click as well. I am uanable to create pagination as I have aprox. 450000 records. How to create the pagination with next and previous button

Comment: Does getRecords() give you the results for just one page?

Comment: @Steven Eckhoff Yes, first 10 records as I am sending limit and offset parameter.

Comment: Okay I updated my example. It shows you the basic mechanisms by which you could achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: @Steven Eckhoff as shown in my ex `<a herf='' onclick='getRecords(1,10,0)'>1</a> ` already working for me but i cannot write this for 450000 records. I want next and previous with 10 pages showing in between.

Comment: You can achieve that using the same basic mechanisms. I have updated the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the most straightforward example I could come up with.

Initially you would populate the results server side with an html template. Or you could have a script do it and populate them similar to how I am doing it in the button click callback.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>JQuery Pagination</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>1</li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#" id="prev">prev</a>
    <span>
    </span>
    <a href="#" id="next">next</a>
</body>
<script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"
        integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    let currentPage = 1
    let $searchList = $("body > ul")
    let $prevButton = $("#prev")
    let $nextButton = $("#next")
    let maxPages = 23
    let maxPageButtons = 5

    let pageButtonClick = function() {
        currentPage = parseInt($(this).text())
        update(currentPage)
        console.log(currentPage)
    }

    let update = function(currentPage) {
        $searchList.children().each(function() {
            $(this).text(currentPage)
        })

        let basePage = currentPage
        if (basePage + maxPageButtons > maxPages) {
            basePage = maxPages - maxPageButtons + 1
        }

        let basePageOffset = 0
        let $newPageButtons = $()
        while (basePageOffset < maxPageButtons) {
            $newPageButtons = $newPageButtons.add(`<a href="#">${basePage + basePageOffset}</a>`)
            basePageOffset++
        }

        $("span").children().remove()
        $("span").append($newPageButtons)

        $("span > a").on("click", pageButtonClick)

        // Get results and display them.
    }

    update(currentPage)

    $prevButton.on("click", function() {
        if (currentPage > 1) {
            currentPage--
            update(currentPage)
        }
    })

    $nextButton.on("click", function () {
        if (currentPage < maxPages) {
            currentPage++
            update(currentPage)
        }
    })
</script>
</html>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3a48fxvg/1/)

If you want to put html in the list item then use the html() method.

Comment: I am checking the maxPage but it is not working in my code. How we can define the max page limit?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the pagination plug-ins you are using are frontend facing. I would suggest to rewrite the querying of data in your backend in a way such that only the required data is sent to the frontend instead of *all* the records. You can use the `limit()`, for *limit*, and `skip()`, for *offset*, mongodb methods interfaces that your driver offers.

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51181206/8565339) to understand how to do this for [mongo-go-driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver). If you are using any other driver, you can use an equivalent of what's being used in the mongo-go-driver.

Comment: I am already using  Find().skip().limit().All(&result) in golang. And My HTML code is like first table show first 10 rows from db and then `<a herf='' onclick='getRecords(1,10,0)'>1</a>` ... page=1,10 is limit and 0 is offset and next would be <a href='getRecords(2,10,10)'>2</a>. I want to do it dynamic with next and prev like pagination

Comment: Please add these details to your original question.